# How to profile javascript in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, profiling

We use PhantomJs 2.0 to take screenshots of web pages. We've found that one particular page takes several minutes to process. This page does not appear to have this issue (or at least not of any comparable magnitude) when loaded in Chrome.

I believe that this is because the javascript is hanging/running very slowly. During the hang, Phantom is using a lot of CPU (although only one core). It does not appear to be taking up an abnormal amount of memory. I am fairly confident that javascript is the culprit because I can see from logging that all requests complete quickly, but then after the page loads Phantom hangs for awhile and won't run anything (I think this is because Phantom is all single-threaded so if the page is still running javascript my Phantom script won't run anything).

I'd like to debug and try to understand what part of the JS is taking so long, but I can't figure out how to get at this in Phantom. For example, I can't seem to collect any output from `console.profile`/`console.profileEnd`. How can I profile the javascript running in Phantom to find the bottleneck?

Comment: You could look at [spy-js](https://github.com/spy-js/spy-js) if you have Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Phantomas](https://github.com/macbre/phantomas), via [grunt-phantomas](https://github.com/stefanjudis/grunt-phantomas). It's a tool that integrates with PhantomJS to profile a wide variety of performance-related metrics. Definitely worth checking out. If it doesn't give you exactly what you need, you can look at the source and see how they integrate with PhantomJS and get data out.